# Missing Python.h and impossible to find

Tags: python, ubuntu

I know there are already similar questions about the missing Python.h but NO solution worked for me by now.

I need Python libraries in order to use Tossim, which is a tinyOS simulator (http://tinyos.net).

Python appears to be already installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 system.
In fact whenever I run the command

```
$ python -V
```

I get the output `2.7.3`

Anyway when I try to locate Python.h no file is found. Python libraries are located in usr/lib/ but no headers in the folder.

Mind that I *already* tried the most common solution for this problem, that is `$ sudo apt-get install python-dev` , and also `$ sudo apt-get update`. 
None of them worked for me.

What should I do now? I tried to remove and reinstall python-dev, with no success. I only think to manually download and place the header into the folder usr/lib/python2.7. 
But I doubt it is a good idea. Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance.`

Comment: What does `dpkg -S Python.h` tell you is installed? You should have a `/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h` file.

Comment: Thank you very much, the Python.h is there as expected. I'm still a newbie... But I wonder why the command "locate Python.h" provided no output. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu (and Debian) stores Python include files in `/usr/include/python2.7`. If the `python2.7-dev` package is installed (a dependency of `python-dev`) then `Python.h` will be located at:

```
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
```

You can locate what packages contain the file with the command:

```
dpkg -S Python.h
```

or list what files are installed with a package with:

```
dpkg -L python2.7-dev
```