# Python.h not found using swig and Anaconda Python

Tags: python, c, macos, swig, anaconda

I'm trying to compile a simple python/C example following this tutorial:

http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html

I'm on MacOS using Anaconda python.

however, when I run

```
gcc -c example.c example_wrap.c -I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include/
```

I get:

```
example_wrap.c:130:11: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
# include <Python.h>
          ^
```

It seems that this problem is reported in a number of questions:

[Missing Python.h while trying to compile a C extension module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097339/missing-python-h-while-trying-to-compile-a-c-extension-module)

[Missing Python.h and impossible to find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170678/missing-python-h-and-impossible-to-find)

[Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041299/python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

but none seem to provide an answer specific to Anaconda on MacOS

Anyone solved this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the option `-I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include/python2.7` in the `gcc` command.  (That's assuming you are using python 2.7.  Change the name to match the version of python that you are using.)  You can use the command `python-config --cflags` to get the full set of recommended compilation flags:

```
$ python-config --cflags
-I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include/python2.7 -I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include/python2.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

However, to build the extension module, I recommend using a simple setup script, such as the following `setup.py`, and let `distutils` figure out all the compiling and linking options for you.

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


example_module = Extension('_example', sources=['example_wrap.c', 'example.c'])

setup(name='example', ext_modules=[example_module], py_modules=["example"])
```

Then you can run:

```
$ swig -python example.i
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

(Take a look at the compiler commands that are echoed to the terminal when `setup.py` is run.)

`distutils` knows about SWIG, so instead of including `example_wrap.c` in the list of source files, you can include `example.i`, and `swig` will be run automatically by the setup script:

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


example_module = Extension('_example', sources=['example.c', 'example.i'])

setup(name='example', ext_modules=[example_module], py_modules=["example"])
```

With the above version of `setup.py`, you can build the extension module with the single command

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Once you've built the extension module, you should be able to use it in python:

```
>>> import example
>>> example.fact(5)
120
```

If you'd rather not use the script `setup.py`, here's a set of commands that worked for me:

```
$ swig -python example.i
$ gcc -c -I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include/python2.7 example.c example_wrap.c 
$ gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/myuser/anaconda/lib example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

Note: I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.4:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Fantastic! It worked. Very clear explanation! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tips of using setup.py~~It works for me on mac osx 10.11~~