# Swig wrapping C++ to python is using default Python rather than Anaconda python in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, swig

I am trying to wrap c++ functions into python using swig. I am using following commands

```
swig -c++ -python helloworld.i
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c hello.cpp
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c helloworld_wrap.cxx -I//anaconda/include/python2.7
g++ -lpython -dynamclib hello.o helloworld_wrap.o -o _helloworld.so
```

with `hello.cpp` being initial file with functions and `helloworld.i` being file with wrapper. These commands creates the library `helloworld`but I can only import it through default python in `/usr/bin/python`

If I try to import it through `python` installed through anaconda it gives following error:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

Can you tell me how can I wrap the codes with `python` from anaconda?

Found a solution : [Python.h not found using swig and Anaconda Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882150/python-h-not-found-using-swig-and-anaconda-python)

In above question, the top answer gives an explanation of using `disutils`and a set up file in python to build the library. This works wonders :)

The next problem I am having for wrapping simple class:

my class code from [example] (http://web.mit.edu/svn/src/swig-1.3.25/Examples/python/class/index.html)

```
/* File : example.h */

class Shape {
public:
  Shape() {
    nshapes++;
  }
  virtual ~Shape() {
    nshapes--;
  };
  double  x, y;   
  void    move(double dx, double dy);
  virtual double area() = 0;
  virtual double perimeter() = 0;
  static  int nshapes;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
    private:
  double radius;
public:
  Circle(double r) : radius(r) { };
  virtual double area();
  virtual double perimeter();
};

class Square : public Shape {
private:
  double width;
public:
  Square(double w) : width(w) { };
  virtual double area();
  virtual double perimeter();
};
```

My `setup.py` file :

```
#setup.py file:

from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(name='example',

    version='0.1',

    ext_modules=[Extension('_example', ['example.h', 'example.i'],
                swig_opts=['-c++'],
                )],

    )
```

Code I am using to wrap :

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Error message:

```
running build_ext
building '_example' extension
swigging example.i to example_wrap.cpp
swig -python -c++ -o example_wrap.cpp example.i
error: unknown file type '.h' (from 'example.h')
```

Can you suggest what is wrong here. I suppose it is not recognizing '.h' file but as it is header file, I thought it could be kept as it is. Also if my `setup.py` file is correct or not? I am just trying to follow example for simple wrapping, there is no simple tutorial online apparently.
I can also ask this question on other different question but thought just continuing here for now.

Comment: Yes, the answer you cite perfectly answers your question (using distutils and even without). So what exactly is the point of posting your question if you already know the answer?

Comment: @m7thon I actually first posted the question and quite a bit later found the solution. So I just added the solution here too. Should I take the question down ? Or how do i say it is closed?

Comment: I see. I guess the best is to just post your found solution as an answer. Then it is clear that the question really is answered.

Comment: okay thank you :) also I wanted to ask few things to you about C++ class wrapping as you seem to be quite knowledgeable in this field. I have classes that has a lot of inheritance to wrap but I am right now trying to work on basic class mainly with this [example](http://web.mit.edu/svn/src/swig-1.3.25/Examples/python/class/index.html) I have added my `setup.py` file that I am using also above and the error I am getting, can you suggest me what is happening. As I told you before I am very new at this and do not have much knowledge in the field. Any help will be well appreciated. :)

Comment: To ask a new question, you should start a new one. Just quickly, as you guessed, you should not be compiling header files. The source files listed in setup.py for your extension should be example.cpp and example.i.

Comment: Please do read the swig documentation. It is very good. For your compilation issues, see for instance the part [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn6).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try to work it out and if something is wrong will post new question. You have been quite helpful and generous with  your suggestions :)Thanks

Comment: @m7thon I got the solution for the above problem with `unknown file type '.h'`apparently I should include the options `headers = ['header/location/header.h']` as  `setup(...., headers=[..])` in `setup.py` seems strange that python disutils file description does not cover this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Warren Weckesser in similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882150/python-h-not-found-using-swig-and-anaconda-python/25883058#25883058) 
. I used the `setup.py` file as suggested in the answer and added the path to the library to `sys.path` and it work wonders :)

Use the option `-I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include/python2.7` in the `gcc` command.  (That's assuming you are using python 2.7.  Change the name to match the version of python that you are using.)  You can use the command `python-config --cflags` to get the full set of recommended compilation flags:

```
$ python-config --cflags
-I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include/python2.7 -I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include/python2.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

However, to build the extension module, I recommend using a simple setup script, such as the following `setup.py`, and let `distutils` figure out all the compiling and linking options for you.

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


example_module = Extension('_example', sources=['example_wrap.c', 'example.c'])

setup(name='example', ext_modules=[example_module], py_modules=["example"])
```

Then you can run:

```
$ swig -python example.i
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

(Take a look at the compiler commands that are echoed to the terminal when `setup.py` is run.)

`distutils` knows about SWIG, so instead of including `example_wrap.c` in the list of source files, you can include `example.i`, and `swig` will be run automatically by the setup script:

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


example_module = Extension('_example', sources=['example.c', 'example.i'])

setup(name='example', ext_modules=[example_module], py_modules=["example"])
```

With the above version of `setup.py`, you can build the extension module with the single command

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Once you've built the extension module, you should be able to use it in python:

```
>>> import example
>>> example.fact(5)
120
```

If you'd rather not use the script `setup.py`, here's a set of commands that worked for me:

```
$ swig -python example.i
$ gcc -c -I/Users/myuser/anaconda/include/python2.7 example.c example_wrap.c 
$ gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/myuser/anaconda/lib example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

Note: I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.4:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```